# Why do Sunni Muslims not reach out to the people of Gaza as stated in Quran?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, sunni, jews, helping

Why do Sunni Muslims not reach out to the people of Gaza as stated in Quran

> [26:277](https://quran.com/26/277): Except those who believe, do good, remember Allah often, and ˹poetically˺ avenge ˹the believers˺ after being wrongfully slandered. The wrongdoers will come to know what ˹evil˺ end they will meet.

and

> [8:72](https://quran.com/8/72): Those who believed, emigrated, and strived with their wealth and lives in the cause of Allah, as well as those who gave them shelter and help—they are truly guardians of one another. As for those who believed but did not emigrate, you have no obligations to them until they emigrate. **But if they seek your help ˹against persecution˺ in faith, it is your obligation to help them**, except against people bound with you in a treaty. Allah is All-Seeing of what you do.

Islam always invites Muslims to help each other, even in very difficult war conditions. So why do we only see the Shiites of Iran, Lebanon, Iraq and Yemen helping the people of Gaza, and we don't see any practical action from the (1.5 billion) Sunni Muslims? Do Sunnis believe that the verses of the Qur'an are abrogated? Even with this view, the Quran has said that Muslims are brothers and sisters.

> [49:10](https://quran.com/49/10): The believers are but one brotherhood, so make peace between your brothers. And be mindful of Allah so you may be shown mercy.

Or the Qur'an has revealed to us the most hostile of all people towards the faithful i.e. a group of Jews

> [5:82](https://quran.com/5/82): Surely You will find the most hostile of all people towards the faithful to be the **Jews** and the **polytheists**, and surely you will find the nearest of them in affection to the faithful to be those who say ‘We are Christians.’ That is because there are priests and monks among them, and because they are not arrogant.

So, with these clear signs from the Quran, why don't Sunni Muslims do anything against US and Israel? What is the use of Sunni Islam if they do not consider themselves obligated to reach out to their religious brother?

Comment: This is a question about Muslim actions and politics and not about Islam itself, so this site is not the correct place for it.

Comment: First of all these are all biased claims and verses accepted by all Muslims no matter which sects they call themselves attached to! Secondly, this question isn't about Islam at all its politically motivated.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Regardless of the motivation of question or profit of whatever political factions are there, it's a fact that civilian muslims are dying/oppressed. The question clearly asks for inaction of muslim community with their obligatory principals, which in no way is illegitimate to ask here.

Comment: @An_Elephant since OP pretends that Sunni are not acting this question is nothing, but causing useless discussions and clearly has a political issue. And in general "Why "X" doesn't do something although Qur'an says so?" isn't a question that we as ISE can answer it is either a rethorical question, a wrong politically motivated claim as it is in this case or an intro to a useless debate. Sunni could also ask why Iran does nothing for Gaza even if they have a combat unit called al-Quds or whatever these kinds of questions are anything but legitimate and not on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Sunnis are under hostile dictators preventing us from attacking, Hamas are sunnis but in general you are correct. There are plenty of jihadis who could be volunteering their help for hezbollah. yemeni sunnis are starting to join houthis. well yemenis are just made out of tantalum or something yemenis dont follow the normal social or physical laws that govern the universe. but its true jihadis could be pouring in or attacking positions in golan and they are not.

a stain on our history to be perfectly frank. there are mitigating factors but imo I dont think we've crossed the threshhold for being excused. we let this trial ferment for a while and now the bill is due. screaming, burning, hack up children everywhere.